# Kindle Fire HD10 media query

Tags: css, media-queries, kindle-fire

I need to write specific styles for Amazon Fire HD 10. So far I have wrote specific styles for other versions. Ex: Fire HD 7, Fire HD 8 like. Following is my current media query code.

```
@media only screen
    and (max-device-width: 1280px)
    and (max-device-height: 800px)
    and (orientation: landscape)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
```

But this codes not working for the `Amazon Fire HD 10`. How can I write `Amazon Fire HD 10` specific styles..? How can I target that only..?

Comment: Do you have access to the device? (can you use it to visit a specific page now?) if so, you can use it and visit http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html to see what media queries apply to it.

Comment: @ILoveCSS Thank you very much. Got the point and I am in my way. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Kindle Fire HD10 so following the advice from @user7234396 in the comments shows me you need to adjust the `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` to 1.5

I also follow [the advice of CSS-Tricks and use min and max device widths](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) rather than using device heights.

Therefore, to target this specific device in landscape orientation as you have in the question, you need

```
@media only screen
    and (min-device-width: 800px)
    and (max-device-width: 1280px)
    and (orientation: landscape)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}
```

Obviously for portrait you need

```
@media only screen
    and (min-device-width: 800px)
    and (max-device-width: 1280px)
    and (orientation: portrait)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}
```